# mage.exe erroring with ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET after 30 minutes

Tags: proxy, clickonce

As part of a ClickOnce deployment I'm running mage.exe

```
mage.exe -Sign "manifest file" -CertFile Cert.pfx -Password yepit5right -TimeStampUri http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
```

the certificate comes from Verisign in the first place so using their timestamping service.

This works fine on some machines but not others, and they come back with the very readable error code of -2147012865 which translates to error 12031 - ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET.

I can connect out through IE on that machine to sites such as stackoverflow.com and so the proxy settings which it needs appear to be correct.

Does mage.exe support authenticating proxies?  This used to work, over a year ago now, before we had a major outbound proxy change which I think included changing from non-authenticating to using integrated authentication at the proxy layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a great answer but it turns out that mage.exe cannot authenticate through to a proxy when making the request out to the timestamping service.

To get around this restriction I have added the source machine and the target URL to our outbound proxy's "whitelist" of requests that are allowed out without requiring proxy authentication.  As you could imaging doing this within a corporate environment where the security team own that list was not a simple task, I much prefer cracking the technical nut.

As soon as this was added mage.exe started behaving as expected, and as it behaves in our test environments which have a non-authenticating proxy.